# Is it possible to export a Macro-Enabled PowerPoint Presentation as a PDF whilst retaining the macro functionality in the PDF?

Tags: pdf, macros, microsoft-powerpoint

For example, I want to create an interactive PDF with hover effects and links in it. I initially created it in PowerPoint, I used a macro to change the color of a button when it was hovered over. However when i export the presentation as a PDF, this hover functionality is lost. Is there anyway to retain it?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks about retaining macro functionality in the PDF.
As @DavidPostill has mentioned, the answer is no.

There is no VBA support in PDF.

But you also ask "However when i export the presentation as a PDF, this hover functionality is lost. Is there anyway to retain it?"

There's no hover highlighting in PDF that I'm aware of, but you *can* change the appearance of the link and how it behaves when clicked by editing the PDF in Acrobat.

Comment: I found these videos though, where there appears to be hover highlighting in PDFs, that's why i thought it was possible > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENwQZm_vWLY https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzEVXrGd2WI

Comment: Hard to say ... in the demo, he talks about previewing the button as an ePub, which is a different format from PDF and may have different capabilities. If you read the comments at the bottom, a couple people are saying that they can't get it to work in PDFs.

Comment: I've done a bit more research, and i've found this document > https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf. It describes "mouseEnter" and "mouseExit" events, which appear to run some javascript (e.g. change button color) when they occur. So this sounds like it could be my solution for getting hover effects in a pdf. :)